# Nested resource routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

How do I trigger `index` method from nested resources?
For example I have route:

```
Route::resource('diagrams.steps', 'DiagramStepsController');
```

I allows URLs like `/diagrams/1/steps/3` which triggers `show($diagramId, $stepID)`.
I would like to get all steps that belong to the diagram with ID 1: `/diagrams/1/steps`.

How do I achieve achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by trigger? Does `/diagrams/1/steps` not work?

Answer (score 2):

The route definition you posted:

```
Route::resource('diagrams.steps', 'DiagramStepsController');
```

Should generate the following routes:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                             | Name                   | Action                         | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD diagrams/{diagrams}/steps              | diagrams.steps.index   | DiagramStepsController@index   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/create       | diagrams.steps.create  | DiagramStepsController@create  |                |               |
|        | POST diagrams/{diagrams}/steps                  | diagrams.steps.store   | DiagramStepsController@store   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/{steps}      | diagrams.steps.show    | DiagramStepsController@show    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/{steps}/edit | diagrams.steps.edit    | DiagramStepsController@edit    |                |               |
|        | PUT diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/{steps}           | diagrams.steps.update  | DiagramStepsController@update  |                |               |
|        | PATCH diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/{steps}         |                        | DiagramStepsController@update  |                |               |
|        | DELETE diagrams/{diagrams}/steps/{steps}        | diagrams.steps.destroy | DiagramStepsController@destroy |                |               |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Notice the very first route is `diagrams/{diagrams}/steps` which calls the `index` method of your controller, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Ok, there was an error in index function in my code. How do I retrieve those steps matching diagram id then?

Comment: I wrote index method as follows:

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('diagrams.steps', 'DiagramStepsController');
```

Gives me    GET|HEAD diagrams/{diagrams}/steps route.
It calls index method with argument matching diagrams id: {diagrams}.
So in order to get all steps that belongs to navigated diagram i had to write method as follows:

```
public function index($id) 
{
    $steps = Step::where('diagram_id', '=', $id)->get();

    return Response::json(
            array(
                'error' => false,
                'steps' => $steps
            ), 
            200
    );
}
```